# sorting a List<List<Integer>> using java Collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list of list  as follow:

```
List<List<Integer>> matchedPostions = findTerms(originalEntPos, singularEntPos, singText);
```

Consider this example

```
[ID,StartPostion,EndPostion]
      ^^^
[1,198,200]
[2,50,61]
```

I am trying to sort list using `Collections.sort()`. How can I sort the values inside the `matchedPostions` based on the `StartPostion` values, from lower to higher values?

Comment: you are trying to sort user defined objects. You will have to use Comparator or comparable interface. These links will help you.http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/

Comment: This does not look like a list of lists of integers. This would be a list of lists: `[1,198,200], [2,50,61]`

Comment: The inner list looks like a coordinate value, why not define a Class for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to implement a `Comparator` to sort custom data-structures like the one you provided.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

List<List<Integer>> matchedPostions = asList(asList(1, 198, 200), asList(2, 50, 61));
Collections.sort(matchedPostions, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
        // Sort the lists using the starting position (second element in the list)
        return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
    }
});

System.out.println(matchedPostions);
// [[2, 50, 61], [1, 198, 200]]
```

This is the "dirty" way. The more idiomatic approach is described Duncan where you implement a `Range` class which properly encapsulates your data.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend you create a class to hold your list values. This allows you to enjoy the benefits of type safety, including being sure you always have exactly two integer values (rather than a unknown number of items in a list). For instance:

```
public class Range implements Comparable<Range> {
    private final int startPosition;
    private final int endPosition;

    public Range(int startPosition, int endPosition) {
        this.startPosition = startPosition;
        this.endPosition = endPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Range o) {
        return startPosition - o.startPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%d,%d]", startPosition, endPosition);
    }
}
```

Because this class implements `Comparable`, you can sort with the normal `Collections.sort method`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Range> ranges = Arrays.asList(new Range(198, 200), new Range(50,
            61));

    System.out.println("Unsorted");
    for (Range range : ranges) {
        System.out.println(range);
    }

    Collections.sort(ranges);

    System.out.println("Sorted");
    for (Range range : ranges) {
        System.out.println(range);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted
[198,200]
[50,61]
Sorted
[50,61]
[198,200]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the inner lists, you can just loop over them:

```
for(List<Integer> inner : outer){
    Collections.sort(inner);
}
```

For the outer List, you need a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't define your own specialized classes for ranges, your can call `Collections.sort` with a your own `Comparator`. Example is below:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
                    return l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sort() in java you can sort easily using lambda function: List<List> ans = new LinkedList<>();

```
ans.sort((x, y) -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(x.size(), y.size()); i++) {
            if (x.get(i) != y.get(i)) {
                return x.get(i) - y.get(i);
            }
        }
        return x.size() - y.size();
    });
```

Its another way for sorting List of List of Integer using lambda function
[Upvote for more such Java solution ♨︎].

Comment: Its another way for sorting List of List of Integer using lambda function  [Upvote for more such Java solution ♨︎].